# 500 internal server error comes up when i use .htaccess file in wamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i was trying to rewrite my post url with htaccess file when i put it into my project directory with following code in the htaccess file 500 internal error comes up, but when i left it(htaccess) blank without any code the page loads perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post post.php
```

Error is:

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

what might be the issue, is there any permission need to be granted or any directives need to be on in config file or php.ini i am new in php development. plz help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post$ post.php
```

Comment: this rule it's not the rule that OP asks, `^post` != `^post$` and both are correct

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^post post.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

With this code the error should disappear but it's possible that your rule is not applying correctly, in this case we will fix

Comment: `You don't have permission to access <path on server to>/post.php on this server.`

Comment: fine, this is good, the rewrite rule it's working. Now you have a permission problem, can you go to othe php page in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, I liked it too, such url  :) `/S:/home/example.com/post.php`

Comment: but, can you create a <path>/test.php in the same folder of post.php and try to access? Appear the same error?